# How to release a beta android app?

Tags: android, beta

I made an android app that I want to release, but it is in beta. I want to know how I should handle this. Should I upload my app with the normal name but with "Beta" after it? Should I change every instance of the name in the app to include Beta after it?

When I want to release the final version, do I delete the beta app and replace it, or just upload another app?

Comment: Play store has a beta program, search online

Answer (score 1):

Google Play has alpha/beta/production release channels.  Within the Alpha/Beta channels you can control distribution through Google+ community membership.

See:

[Google Developer Console Alpha/Beta](https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/developer-console.html#alpha-beta)

[Staging Play Store Rollouts](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)

When you want to release to the production Play store you promote the app directly from Beta in the Developer Console.